# Memory speed tradeoff of sorting algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, memory, complexity-theory

Consider only the bubble sort and merge sort. For bubble sort, time complexity would be O(n) to worst case O(n^2) and space complexity O(1). For merge sort, time complexity would be O(nlogn) with space complexity O(n). Which sort would you choose if the size of input is less than 1000 and why? What about more than 1000?

This is an interview question I had. Just want to know how you guys would answer it.

Comment: What you choose depends on what criteria you use to evaluate. I would choose "quickest to code cleanly" for a small sort, and never mind any performance considerations. This sounds awfully like homework...

Comment: Depends on a HUGE number of things. For example, how much memory do you have? Are you sorting in memory or file? Is the data likely to be near sorted? Is going parallel an option?

Comment: `input is less than 1000` - Just use bubble sort or any O(n^2) sorting algorithm, if it is simpler for you to code. `What about more than 1000` Mergesort/Quicksort or even hybrid of Quick Sort + Insertion Sort.

Comment: Bubble sort also has linear memory complexity. You have to put your array in memory at some point.

Comment: @double_squeeze but it can overlap with the input. Then again, there's also an in-place variant of merge sort, but that isn't O(n log n) anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider only the bubble sort and merge sort.

By less than 1000, it might mean RAM is enough for any sorting algorithm without external storage. It also implies that the theoretical bound for time complexity doesn't matter in this case. You can pick any sorting algorithm you like without incurring any time penalty. For example, you can do bubble sort since it may be easy and intuitive to implement. Merge sort is just as good.

When the input size is bigger than 1000, it is probably assuming that the time complexity matters and even that RAM may not be big enough without external storage. In this case, if you have to choose between the two, merge sort is the safe one to pick. This is because merge sort has better worst case performance over bubble sort and merge sort is a good candidate for [external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)(when input size is bigger than RAM).

Comment: 10000 or even 10^7 usually pose no problem for PC, and will become problem when we are dealing with very limited resource constraint. Quick sort (hybrid with insertion sort) is an option for PC case.

Comment: @nhahtdh I agree. That's typically what we do in practice.